# How can I inject a suffix into a \@currentlabel anchor with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref

Ultimately, I'd like an injection hook in `\@currentlabel` to add a suffix to the anchor like this: `\edef\@currentlabel{\p@counter\thecounter<HOOK>}` with `hyperref` loaded. I thought about redefining `\refstepcounter`, but 
`hyperref` throws some wrenches into the system by redefining `\refstepcounter`:

```
\let\H@refstepcounter\refstepcounter


\def\refstepcounter#1{%
  \ifHy@pdfstring
  \else
    \H@refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\This@name{#1}%
    \ifx\This@name\name@of@slide
    \else
      \if@skiphyperref
      \else
        \if@hyper@item
          \stepcounter{Item}%
          \hyper@refstepcounter{Item}%
          \@hyper@itemfalse
        \else
          \hyper@refstepcounter{#1}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

I also had a look at `\hyper@refstepcounter`, but to no avail.

## Desired Behavior

If I inject "en-US", I'd see `subsubsection.1.1.1:en-US` as field[4] of `\contentsline`:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}}{1}{subsubsection.1.1.1:en-US}}
```

I know how to use `\theHsection`, for example

```
\renewcommand*\theHsection{\thesection:en-US}
```

but that will yield `subsubsection.1:en-US.1.1:`. I am looking for a solution that will add a suffix regardless of the base content. I could not find a hint in the source code `/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty`. I could also not find where `hyperref` actually uses `\theHsection`.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter% allow @ to access backend commands
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{}
\meaning\This@name% section

\subsection{}
\meaning\This@name % subsection

\subsubsection{}
\meaning\This@name %subsubsection

\paragraph{}
\meaning\This@name % subsubsection if not redefined

\end{document}
```

## Aux

Relevant parts

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}}{1}{section.1:en-US}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}}{1}{subsection.1:en-US.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}}{1}{subsubsection.1:en-US.1.1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {paragraph}{}{1}{section*.2}}
```

## Why

Well, suppose I have a bunch of files merged into a single PDF using `\input`. Each file represents a different language-country version of the same document. Because I must restart the sectioning counters, the links will overlap, so the easiest way is to use a generic counter with `hyperref` by setting `hypertexnames=false`. However, this effectively disables/removes any any relation between the PDF anchor and where it came from.  To keep anchors semantically related to their corresponding language-country version, I would like to keep `hypertexnames=true` and just add a variable suffix to the anchors that indicates the source language-country version from which it came. Why suffix? It is my opinion that it is nice to read that way with a `:` separator. A prefix would be ok too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Destination level for merging PDF files

Package `hyperref` can modify the destination labels via the macro `\HyperDestNameFilter`. It can be used to append the suffix `:en-US`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{#1:en-US}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{First section}    
  \subsection{First subsection}    
  \subsubsection{First subsubsection}    
  \paragraph{First paragraph}    
\end{document}
```

The destination names in the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.toc`) are not changed, because `\HyperDestNameFilter` is applied at low level, the `hyperref` driver level.
But all the destination names in the PDF file have the suffix:

```
(Doc-Start:en-US)
(page.1:en-US)
(section*.1:en-US)
(section*.2:en-US)
(section.1:en-US)
(subsection.1.1:en-US) 
(subsubsection.1.1.1:en-US)
```

## Counter level for merging TeX files

If the merging is done at TeX level with no longer unique counter values, then macro `\theH<counter>` for the clashing counters need to be redefined. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\NewLanguage}[1]{%
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand*{\theHsection}{%
    \the\value{section}:#1%
  }%
  % The redefinitions for subsection, subsubsection
  % is usually not needed, because they use \theHsection.
  % But for better names:
  \renewcommand*{\theHsubsection}{%
    \the\value{section}.\the\value{subsection}:#1%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\theHsubsubsection}{%
    \the\value{section}.\the\value{subsection}%
    .\the\value{subsubsection}:#1%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

\NewLanguage{en-US}

  \section{First section (en)}
  \subsection{First subsection (en)}
  \subsubsection{First subsubsection (en)}

\NewLanguage{de-DE}

  \section{First section (de)}
  \subsection{First subsection (de)}
  \subsubsection{First subsubsection (de)}

\end{document}
```

The `.toc` file (with additional spaces for better alignment):

```
\contentsline {section}      {\numberline {1}First section (en)}{1}          {section.1:en-US}
\contentsline {subsection}   {\numberline {1.1}First subsection (en)}{1}     {subsection.1.1:en-US}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}First subsubsection (en)}{1}{subsubsection.1.1.1:en-US}
\contentsline {section}      {\numberline {1}First section (de)}{1}          {section.1:de-DE}
\contentsline {subsection}   {\numberline {1.1}First subsection (de)}{1}     {subsection.1.1:de-DE}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}First subsubsection (de)}{1}{subsubsection.1.1.1:de-DE}
```

Comment: @JonathanKomar It is unclear, how the different languages are merged. If there is a tool that merges PDF files and can keep annotations, then `\HyperDestNameFilter` is a good start, because the files will then have unique destination names. Otherwise, redefine `\theH<counter>` for the counters that clashes with the same values otherwise.

Comment: FEATURE REQUEST (can I make those here?): pre and post hooks to `\@currentlabel`. Reason being: Assume I have a bunch of `\theHcounter`s for various document elements e.g. tables, figures, examples, formulas, theorems, questions, answers, sections, subsections etc.. Your solution means that I would have to add all of these redefs to `\NewLanguage`. Wouldn't it be cleaner (and less error-prone) to have a hook that is applied to all `\@currentlabel`s for the language-country code?

Comment: @JonathanKomar It is *not* so easy. Example page destinations that are used in the index rely on *not* having any additions. The bunch of counters is quick and easy to setup. And pdfTeX warns with duplicate destination warnings, if a counter is missed to setup properly.